# ESP warning light on

Tags: sensor, audi, esp-esc

**Audi A3 8PA 2005my 1.9tdi**
Esp warning light is on and diagnosis with VCDS shows fault :-
`00493-ESP-Sensor unit (G419): No signal/Communication`
No other warning lights are showing. I have tried replacing the sensor unit with a refurbished one (10 year guarantee?) as the dealers wanted over £700 for one. Warning Light failed to clear, so the firm sent another one- still no joy.
I'm not sure if the fault is with the sensor unit (lateral acceleration) or something else as it could also be bad wiring or connectors from brake electronics, abs unit, to esp sensor.
How do I go about diagnosing and fixing the issue? 
As there are two possible faults, sensor unit or connectors/wiring I felt it was best to eliminate the sensor so that is why I used the less expensive refurbished units. No way of knowing if they were in working order. Does anybody know how I could test the sensor unit to see if it is working, the original is back in the car? If this is the problem then I will replace with OEM and save time/expense testing connectors/wiring.

Just to let you know, the ESP warning light first came on during a journey and stayed on for the rest of the day. The next day it was on first thing but during the day went out upon starting and stayed out for about 1/2 mile then came back on. It has stayed on ever since. Does this indicate anything?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Voltage meter. Always check whether a device CAN communicate first.

Comment: Agree with @JuannStrauss. I would add to take a close look at all the connectors between them, corrosion of the terminals could be an issue at 10 years (and it is cheap and easy to check).

Comment: How do I check sender unit and garage wants car for 3 days to check connectors/wiring so not cheap.